# In sed, how to represent "alphanumeric or _ or -"

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

Tried

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_]
[a-zA-Z0-0\-\_]
[[[:alnum:]]-_]
...
```

What is the correct way to represent that in regular expression?

It seems like [a-zA-Z0-9-] works for alphanumeric or dash. But when I add another underscore, it breaks.

Comment: Always put the hyphen last in the list of characters in the set.  Otherwise it is interpreted as part of a range specification.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That will be this character class:

```
[[:alnum:]_-]
```

Which means allow one of these:

```
1. Alpha numeric
1. Underscore
1. Hyphen
```

It is important to keep hyphen at 1st or last position in character class to avoid escaping.

Comment: To elaborate, if an _un_ escaped hyphen - shows up anywhere but the very first or last position, the regex processor thinks you want a _range_ rather than a lone character.

Comment: To fetch alphanumeric characters of a file


sed '/^[^-[:alnum:]]/d' file

Comment: for some reason, the `[[:alnum:]_-]` somehow match the forward slash too and followed by 1 more letter. meaning, it somehow match things like this: `abcdef/somethingelse` as `abcdef/s`

Comment: No that cannot match a `/`. That would be because of absence of anchors.

Answer (score 1):

All of these variations will work:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]
[-_a-zA-Z0-9]
[-a-z_A-Z0-9]
[-a-zA-Z_0-9]
[-a-zA-Z0-9_]
...
```

The hyphen needs to be on one end. It can be escaped or not if at the end, and must be un-escaped if at the beginning. The underscore can be almost anywhere, as long as it's not in the middle of one of your ranges, and doesn't need to be escaped.